# Creating a List of only Whole Numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

I am trying to create a list of only whole numbers from another list. Suppose my range list is:

[image]

I want the results to appear as:

[image]

I want the solution to work in excel 2019 only. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have office 365 you could use `=FILTER(A1:A6,INT(A1:A6)=A1:A6)`
For older versions: `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$6,SMALL(IF(INT($A$1:$A$6)=$A$1:$A$6,ROW($A$1:$A$6)),ROWS($1:1))),"")` this should be entered with`ctrl+shift+enter`

Comment: The formula seems to work well in an empty worksheet, however I get a different result if the formula is in a workbook that has other tables in it.

Comment: If the range starts at a different row than the first row you need to subtract the number of rows from row 1 to the first row number in your range. For instance if you have Range `$A$6:$A$11` then you need to use `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$6:$A$11,SMALL(IF(INT($A$6:$A$11)=$A$6:$A$11,ROW($A$6:$A$11)-5),ROWS($1:1))),"") I also noticed a typo in my original formula which I corrected

Answer (score 0):

So use MOD():
[image]

Or, you can return the number:
[image]

And to make a list without spaces, you can use LARGE() or UNIQUE() whatever works for you, even sorting may work if you don't expect automatic.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Ideally it should all be automated. How would the formula look like without spaces using the LARGE() or UNIQUE() function? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @MochaLatte I will let you play and learn since you have now unaccepted my answer.